# Java code for creating Hadoop Archive

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop-archive

I am developing an application for creating 1 Hadoop Archive files from millions of small files. I have successfully tested that with command line(`hadoop archive --archiveName foo.har -p / -r 2 test.txt /`) but i am not able to find out any resources to do it programmatically.

Any idea how to create Hadoop Archive using an client application?